# Can this While loop be simplified?

Tags: java, string, java-8, stack, parentheses

Consider the following code. It is for check if the String has valid parenthesis but without using stack.

```java
public boolean isValid(String input) {
       
    while(input.length() != (input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}", "")).length());
    return input.isEmpty();
}
```

But Kinda difficult to understand. Can this be simplified? Without adding more number of new lines?

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? More understandable? _Even fewer_ lines? Fewer characters?

Comment: Can you mention, what you are trying to do with this `while` loop? Maybe the `while` loop is not needed entirely.

Comment: Yeah I want this code to be more understandable and readable @Sweeper

Comment: @boobalan this while loop is removing all the pairs of parenthesis from the string and approach is kind of similiar to when we read file data ` while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { `

Comment: @AashishPawar Then it necessarily adds more lines of code. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Yeah its fine all I said not to add many lines . if is < 4 or 5 lines then its okay

Comment: What do you mean by "valid parenthesis"? Does `"(foo)bar)"` has valid parenthesis?

Comment: No string is only contains pair of parenthesis . I used this snippet to solve this question https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

Comment: At a glance, I don't think this works anyway. I think it rejects "([])" which Is surely correctly-bracketed.  And making it accept that, but reject "([)]", is rather more complicated.

Comment: Nope 1 @user13784117 It will return true for ([])

Comment: Oh, you're right. It works from "inside out". I was looking at the regexp and ignoring the loop. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It helps if you first format and indent it properly:

```
public boolean isValid_2(String input) {
    while(input.length() != (input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}", "")).length())
        ;
    return input.isEmpty();
}
```

Next, notice that the method doesn't depend on instances of its class, so can be static. Also, remove redundant escapes from the regex:

```
public static boolean isValid_3(String input) {
    while(input.length() != (input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[]|\\{}", "")).length())
        ;
    return input.isEmpty();
}
```

Finally, break up the complicated statement into easy-to-understand parts, and introduce some variables with meaningful names, and then change the type of loop to something more useful, and you have your final version:

```
public static boolean isValid_4(String input) {
    int oldLength, newLength;
    do {
        oldLength = input.length();
        input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[]|\\{}", "");
        newLength = input.length();
    } while (oldLength != newLength);
    return input.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: I'd add one more step, extracting that RE into a constant.

Answer (score 3):

My simplification is this:

```
static boolean isValid(String input) {
    String t = input, s;
    do {
        s = t;
        t = s.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}", "");
    } while (s.length() != t.length());
    return t.isEmpty();
}
```

which, though longer, makes it easier IMO to see what's going on.  I like brevity, but it's not always best.

This differs from other simplification answers in that it focuses more on the remaining strings than on the lengths, which to my mind is more to the point. But at some point, this is a matter of aesthetics.

(Also, you can conveniently stick a "print" after the assignments in the loop, to see what is really happening - I did this to debug my incorrect comment)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The question has been updated after I've answered the question. So, if doesn't fulfill the questions answer's each and every aspect, then please just ignore it**.

let's see:

```java
public boolean isValid(String input) {
    
    int prevLength = input.length();

    input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}", "");
    
    while(prevLength != input.length()) {
        prevLength = input.length();
        input = input.replaceAll("\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}", "");
    }
    
    return input.isEmpty();
}
```

I guess its enough simplified...

Comment: Yeah ! This looks elegant

Comment: @AashishPawar, yeah! then what are you waiting for, accept it as best answer :P

Comment: @AashishPawar Actually it is not as elegant as it looks at first glance. The regex gets compiled at each and every iteration.

Comment: @reyad Begging for votes and asking the OP to accept your answer is considered a bad tone in SO community. Let people decide how good it is.

Comment: @reyad I did. That's why I upvoted your answer. Although I still find that comment inappropriate for SO.

Comment: well, if you really think the comment is inappropriate, I won't comment like it again. I have respect for your suggestion and also the community.